# Trying to display number of rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, ejs

I'm trying to display the number of rows of a column inside a html card, I'm using ejs to insert data

This is the code for the insertion

```
app.get('/home', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await db.query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (unidadeconsumidora)) FROM unidadeconsumidora');
  console.log('result:', result);
  const ucCount = result.rows[0].count;
  console.log('ucCount:', ucCount);
  res.render('home', { ucCount: ucCount });
});
```

But isnt displaying none of the info in the console

This is the error I got

C:\DEV\crm\server\src\app.js:378
const ucCount = result.rows[0].count;
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at C:\DEV\crm\server\src\app.js:378:30
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: What does `result` return?

Comment: It should return the value of the query

Comment: It *should*, but *does* it in reality? And if so, what's its format?

Comment: I dont know if it does, it returns undefined result: undefined

Comment: Then *there's* your problem. You need to determine why it's not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the result is an array not object!

Give an alias to your column example `count`, then you will have to catch it using `result[0][0].count`

```
app.get('/home', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await db.query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (unidadeconsumidora)) as count FROM unidadeconsumidora');
  console.log('result:', result[0]);
  const ucCount = result[0][0].count;
  console.log('ucCount:', ucCount);
  res.render('home', { ucCount: ucCount });
});
```

Comment: It returned the same error   

const ucCount = result[0][0].count;
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at C:\DEV\crm\server\src\app.js:378:28
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: Can you share the result of this log : console.log('result:', result);

Comment: It came undefined result: undefined